# R code to generate numbers in sequence and insert rows

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns. First column is an ID and the 2nd will column is the total number of quarters. If the Col B(quarters) has the value 8, then the 8 rows should be created starting from 1 to 8. The ID in col A should be the same for all rows. The dataset shown below is an example.

```
ID        Quarters
A         5
B         2
C         1
```

Expected output

```
ID       Quarters
A         1
A         2
A         3
A         4
A         5
B         1
B         2
C         1
```

Here is what I tried.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.WQuarter)[, (Quarters=1:Quarters), ID]
```

I get this error. Can you please help. I am really stuck at this for the whole day. I am just learning the basics of R.

Comment: The code as posted works

Comment: Why did you ask the same question again?  You had three answers on the linked duplicate.

Comment: The issue is with `NA` values. `df1[, (Quarters = sequence(na.omit(Quarters))), by = ID]`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R` to replicate the 'ID' by 'Quarters' and create the 'Quarters' by taking the `sequence` of that column.

```
with(df1, data.frame(ID= rep(ID, Quarters), Quarters = sequence(Quarters)))
#   ID Quarters
#1  A        1
#2  A        2
#3  A        3
#4  A        4
#5  A        5
#6  B        1
#7  B        2
#8  C        1
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', get the `sequence` of 'Quarters' or just `seq(Quarters)`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Quarters=sequence(Quarters)) , by = ID]
```

As @PierreLaFortune commented on the post, if we have NA values, then we need to remove it

```
setDT(df1)[, .(Quarters = seq_len(Quarters[!is.na(Quarters)])), by = ID]
```

---

Or using the `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(Quarters = list(seq(Quarters))) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     unnest(Quarters)
```

---

If the OP's "Quarters" column is non-numeric, it should be converted to 'numeric' before proceeding

```
 df1$Quarters <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Quarters))
```

The `as.character` is in case if the column is `factor`, but if it is `character` class, `as.numeric` is enough.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Quarters = c(5L, 2L, 1L
)), .Names = c("ID", "Quarters"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun...I tried the base R code like you suggested. I get this error. Error in rep(ID, Quarters) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: For the second option, I get this error. Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer Can you please help?

Comment: @user2341632  Please check the `str(yourdata)`, I think you have a 'TotalQuarters' column non-numeric.  I updated the post with the data.  It is working for me.

Comment: Here is my data structure. Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 86 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ID           : chr  "C.1" "M.1" "R.0" "N.3" ...
 $ TotalQuarters: num  1 9 9 9 10 9 9 13 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

Comment: @user2341632 In that case, the data.table method should work on that.

Comment: @PierreLafortune `1:Quarters` is not a good option when the Quarters is 0

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer I meant `seq_len`.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer  I don't check all the `user12333` numbers whether they post a question or not.  If I check it, I will dupe it as you might have seen that some post I duped it the minute it was posted.  I didn't check that deleted answer to copy/paste the answer.  I guess the code was in my mind.

Comment: After reading yesterday's question their problem is with NA values. That is why their solutions did not work. Maybe add `df1[, (Quarters = sequence(na.omit(Quarters))), by = ID]`

Comment: Thank you so much everybody for the help. na.omit helps. It works perfectly. Just a small doubt. Is there a way that we can make this work only for numbers ignoring  NAs and other text entries. BTW, I am sure that akrun's code setDT(df1)[, .(Quarters = seq_len(Quarters[!is.na(Quarters)])), by = ID] should also work. I havent tested it yet as I just left the office.

Comment: @user2341632  If there are text entries, you can convert to `numeric` then automatically, all those non-numeric entries becomes NA and then use the same code with `!is.na`. i.e. convert by `as.numeric(as.character(` or `as.numeric` if it is a character class